# Sorting number string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two numbers of different length:

`"103"` and `"11"`

In irb:

```
2.1.1 :005 > "11" > "103"
=> true 
2.1.1 :006 > "11" < "103"
=> false
```

Why does this happen? I understand I can to a `.to_i` for each string, but if this is a rails query where the column type is string, anything I can do about this?

Comment: Do you want them sorted by length, numeric value, or alphabetically (which is what it appears to be doing)?

Comment: This sounds like you want `sort_by`.  Or just sort within your database?

Comment: Can you show the Rails query and what your code context is for making the comparison? It's not clear to me why you can't customize the comparison using `.to_i`.

Answer (score 6):

Strings are sorted [*lexicographically*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) which means that "1" comes after "0", and "103" comes before "11", and before "1122344", and before "1abc".

You cannot compare strings as if they were numbers, you need to parse them as numbers before you can do that.

The only way I can think of, is to make sure they are padded with enough zeroes before they are turned into a string: `"000103", "000011"`...

Answer (score 2):

Strings are being compared character by character. Hence `'11' > '103'` execution stops on a second character and returns true, since `'1'.chr > '0'.chr`

Answer (score 1):

They are strings. And they are compared by `String#ord` value.
So `'1'.ord # => 49` and `'0'.ord # => 48`. That is why

```
'11' > '10' # => true
# and
'11' > '100' # => true
```

as well as

```
'b' > 'a' # => true
'a'.ord # => 97
'b'.ord # => 98
# and
'b' > 'aaaaa' # => still true
```